# How to delete specific LD_FLAG in xcconfig through Podfile script?

Tags: xcode, podfile, ldflags

I am trying to delete a certain "-framework SwiftProtobuf" in OTHER_LDFLAGS from the .xcconfig file in XCode because it is causing a conflict with another library:

"Class _TtC13SwiftProtobuf17AnyMessageStorage is implemented in both SwiftProtobuf.framework/SwiftProtobuf and [MyX].app. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined".

I am able to do so manually from the .xcconfig file by deleting "-framework "SwiftProtobuf" and solve my problem, however it is automatically re-generated once I install the pods again.

Anyone knows a script I can add to my Podfile to permanently remove a specific framework linker flag?